# Sharepoint 2013 powershell script running but nothing happens

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Sow i want to be able too change the title of my webpart (project links) in sp2013 as a learning project.
It runs but nothing actually happens and my testenviroment is correctly linked..

```
'''

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$sourcewebURL = ".."
$siteURL = ".."

$list = ""
$pageName = ""
$Page = ""

$project_x0020_number = read-host""
$spLink = read-host""
$spoldLink = "Title"
$spNewLink= read-host""

if("Title" -eq $SpLink)
{
$webpartdefinition.Webpart.Properties.Add("Title")
$site.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$true
$web.AllowUnsafeUpdates=$true
}

write-host"...."

'''
```

Comment: There are at least three uninitialised variables. Is that intentional?

Comment: not very much ive been going st this for a while now. and i think i might have gone overboard a bit haha. any advice is very welcome